# Python: Returning parsed info to a list?

Tags: python, parsing, for-loop, return, beautifulsoup

My code:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://realpython.com/practice/profiles.html"

html_page = urlopen(url)
html_text = html_page.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)

links = soup.find_all('a', href = True)

files = []

def page_names():
    for a in links:
        files.append(a['href'])
        return files


page_names()

print files[:]

base = "https://realpython.com/practice/"

print base + files[:]
```

I'm trying to parse out three webpage file names and append them to "files" list, then somehow append or add them to the end of the base url for a simple print.

I've tried making "base" a single item list so I could append, but I am rather new to Python and believe I'm screwing up my for statement.

Currently I get:

```
print files[:]
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: `links = soup.find_all('a', href = True)`

Comment: Still the same error, but thank you.

Comment: You haven't defined a `list`, so it's still the built-in type. Did you mean `print links` (no need for a shallow copy on printing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the last you have defined `list[:]`, it's completely wrong since `list` is a built-in keyword for creating actual list.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://realpython.com/practice/profiles.html"

html_page = urlopen(url)
html_text = html_page.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)

links = soup.find_all('a', href = True)

files = []

def page_names():
    for a in links:
        files.append(a['href'])


page_names()


base = "https://realpython.com/practice/"
for i in files:
    print base + i
```

**Output:**

```
https://realpython.com/practice/aphrodite.html
https://realpython.com/practice/poseidon.html
https://realpython.com/practice/dionysus.html
```

And you don't need to create intermediate list for storing links or files just use list_comprehension.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://realpython.com/practice/profiles.html"
html_page = urlopen(url)
html_text = html_page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)
files = [i['href'] for i in soup.find_all('a', href = True)]
base = "https://realpython.com/practice/"
for i in files:
    print base + i
```